# Употребление слова "отдельно"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, стили-речи

Нужно написать человеку, что для приобретения отдельного продукта, входящего в комплекс предоставляемых продуктов, нужно сделать определенные действия. Корректна ли следующая фраза:

**Для приобретения *отдельно* роз, пожалуйста, обратитесь в ...**?

Comment: Розы не могут входить в число продуктов. И  перечень, список, пакет, корзина, набор, заказ, но не — «комплекс» продуктов.

Comment: Я понимаю о чем Вы. Слово розы было взято как пример. Я не могу привести оригинальный текст. Вопрос был насколько корректно употреблени слова "отдельно" таким образом с грам. точки зрения.

Comment: Роза - продукт выращивания из семян :) .

Comment: Я ем розы (в вареном виде) :)

Comment: Комплекс воооот такой, а зовут Розочка.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы употребляете слово "пожалуйста", то в том же нестрогом стиле лучше написать: "Если вы хотите приобрести только розы, обратитесь, пожалуйста, в ..."

Если вы хотите придерживаться официального стиля, воспользуйтесь советом Alex_ander: "Для приобретения роз отдельно от предлагаемого комплекса продуктов
обратитесь в ..."

Comment: Большое спасибо.Было интересно возможно ли построение такой фразы с грамматической точки зрения в принципе.

Answer (score 1):

**Для приобретения роз, не входящих в (базовый) комплект, пожалуйста, обратитесь в ...**

Может быть, лучше **комплект, чем комплекс**?

**КОМПЛЕКС**,  1. Совокупность, **сочетание предметов**, явлений, действий, свойств. К. гимнастических упражнений. Космический к.  Промышленный к.  Архитектурный к.

**КОМПЛЕКТ**, 1. **Полный набор каких-л. предметов**, в совокупности составляющих целое.  К. запасных частей машины.

Answer (score 0):

Фраза *корректна*, но она непонятна вне контекста, который лучше ввести в саму фразу, например:

> Для приобретения роз отдельно от предлагаемого комплекса продуктов
>
> обратитесь туда-то.

Либо нужно *предварительно* объяснить, что ещё нужно обязательно купить вместе с розами.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Да, сначала отдельным абзацем идет опеределение, что именно есть предоставляемый комплекс и входящие компоненты.  Вопрос возник именно к тому, правильно ли грамматически построена указанная фраза.